# Minify/Uglify my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

My app that I want to run in Chrome/Firefox is:

- written in typescript
- uses react
- written with es next features (modules, imports, etc)
- has some import that are plain js files
- webpack 3

I can build and run my app fine without minifying but when I try to minify/uglify, thatis call webpack with `--optimize-minimize`, I get:

> ERROR in ./dist/app.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (App) [./src/app.tsx:34,0][./dist/app.js:40677,6]

What could be causing this?

I know this one might be a tough one to answer, but what I'm looking for is the config for an app that uses the same list of items that I am so that I can replicate it. How do I transpile to current Ecmascript in browsers and also minify my app? Thanks.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const resolve = require('path').resolve;
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app.tsx",
  output: {
      filename: "app.js",
      path: __dirname
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src')],
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /src/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
      { test: /\.css?$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'mapbox-gl$': resolve('./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js')
    },
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
  }
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "esnext",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["src/typings/*", "*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

My .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets":  [
        ["env", {
            "modules": false,
            "forceAllTransforms": true
        }]
      ],
    "plugins": ["transform-object-assign"]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to comments by Niba and post by Sebastian, I got rid of `--optimize-minimize` and installed the `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` and added it to my webpack.config.js (below). The error went away however the page didn't display everything (specifically mapbox tiles), showing an ambiguous `t is undefined` console error. Setting `compress: false` fixed the issue however the files obviously aren't as small as they could be. There's a lot of compression options so I feel it's going to be difficult to track this issue down.

My updated webpack.config.js:

```
const resolve = require('path').resolve;
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = (env) => {
  const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
  return {
    entry: "./src/app.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: __dirname
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          include: [resolve('src')],
          exclude: [/node_modules/]
        },
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /src/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
        { test: /\.css?$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'mapbox-gl$': resolve('./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js')
      },
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    plugins: isDevBuild ? [
    ] : [
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: false,
          mangle: true
        }
      })
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Make sure that you are using a good version of uglifyjs. There are two versions, one for es5 which is built in Webpack - webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin and another one for es6 which is distributed as a separate package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

Comment: Thanks @niba, the plugin got me further (post updated).

Comment: Did you try setting an ECMA version, like described in the answer below?

Comment: @SebastianSebald I did, I tried ecma 5 to 8 in both and separately uglifyOptions and compress options. No luck.

Comment: Hm. Can you upload a minimal example of your project, so we can check it out?

Answer (score 1):

Using `--optimize-minimize` will use [UglifyJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) to minimize your code. My guess is that the default configuration tries to minimize Es5, bus since your `target` for TypeScript is set to `esnext`, UglifyJS can not handle that.

You have two options:

1. Set your target to ES5
2. Play with the [configuration](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony#minify-options) (in your webpack config), set `ecma` to `8` or something.

---

Even though webpack's documentation says that `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` uses the `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` under the hood, I am not sure with what version of webpack that is. Also, maybe the default configuration just does not work in your case :)

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I tried both of your suggestions without much luck, however using the UglifyJsPlugin in webpack.config.js has got me closer (post updated).